# Visit nodes as per the rule and delete all the unvisited nodes in the linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to traverse a linked list according to the value of the head pointer in linked list because a node contains two values the value of the current and the pointer to the next . I have to traverse in following fashion
[image]

Initially, you are at the head (Node with value 1). So you move to the 1st node after that which is the node with value 2.

From node 2 you visit the 2nd node after that which is the node with value 1.

In a similar way, you go to the second last node (value = 2).

From there since there are less than 2 nodes you reach NULL and stop.

So, the visited nodes are 1, 2, 1, and 2

```
 /*
    public class ListNode {
       public int val; 
       public ListNode next;
       public ListNode(int x) { val = x; next = null; }
    }
    */
    
    public class Solution {
        satic void deleteUnvisitedNodes(ListNode head) {
            ListNode current = head;
            ListNode temp;
            while(current != null){
                int k = current.val;
                temp = NthNode(current,k);
                current.next = temp.next;
            }
        }
    
           static  ListNode NthNode(ListNode head, int k){
                int count = 0;
                ListNode current = head;
                while(current !=null && current.next!=null){
                    if(count == k)
                        return current;
                    count++;
                    current = current.next;
                    }
                    return current;
                }
              public static void main(String[] args){
    ListNode head = null;
    head = new ListNode(1);
    head.next = new ListNode(2);
    head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
    head.next.next.next = new ListNode(1);
    head.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(2);
    head.next.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(3);
    ArrayList<ListNode> l = new ArrayList<>();
    deleteUnvisitedNodes(head);
    while(head != null){
        l.add(head);
        head = head.next;
    }
    System.out.print(l);
}
```

I am getting a runtime error

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: But its like a weird runtime notihng is displaying @Arnaud similar to online code editor timeout exception

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are not moving ahead after deleting the unvisited node in `deleteUnvisitedNodes` method which is causing an infinite number of executions and hence a timeout. So, after deleting the unvisited node we need to move ahead to the `N-th` node and continue the process.
Here is the working code with desired output:

```
class ListNode
{
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int x)
    { val = x; next = null; }
}
class Solution
{
    void deleteUnvisitedNodes(ListNode head)
    {
        ListNode current = head;
        ListNode temp;
        while (current != null)
        {
            int k = current.val;
            temp = NthNode(current,k);
            current.next = temp;
            current = current.next; // or current = temp // <-- Modified
        }
    }
    
    ListNode NthNode(ListNode head, int k)
    {
        int count = 0;
        ListNode current = head;
        while (current != null && current.next != null)
        {
            if (count == k)
                return current;
            ++count;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return null; // <-- Modified
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ListNode a = new ListNode(1); ListNode b = new ListNode(2);
        ListNode c = new ListNode(3); ListNode d = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode e = new ListNode(2); ListNode f = new ListNode(3);
        
        a.next = b; b.next = c; c.next = d; d.next = e; e.next = f;
        ListNode head = a;
        while (head != null)
        {
            System.out.print(head.val + " -> ");
            head = head.next;
        }System.out.println("null");
        
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        sol.deleteUnvisitedNodes( a );
        
        head = a;
        while (head != null)
        {
            System.out.print(head.val + " -> ");
            head = head.next;
        }System.out.println("null");
    }
}
```

Output :

**1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> null**
**1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 2 -> null**
Feel free to ask any query.

Answer (score 1):

@GURU Shreyansh's solution will fail for the following test case:

I/P:

334 - No of nodes

```
6 7 3 6 1 1 5 6 1 9 9 1 9 10 7 9 1 3 4 1 7 9 2 9 10 6 10 4 8 1 2 4 9 6 8 5 3 7 4 2 
1 10 4 7 3 3 10 3 8 10 4 2 6 2 7 1 2 1 9 3 1 8 4 9 5 6 2 1 3 4 10 1 1 10 1 2 6 1 5
9 5 6 4 2 6 1 9 5 1 4 2 2 7 4 5 3 6 7 4 5 2 5 2 7 6 7 5 4 6 4 4 2 1 5 6 8 5 4 10 2
9 10 8 8 8 6 10 2 7 7 10 4 2 9 10 3 9 9 7 7 2 6 2 6 10 9 10 4 4 1 6 5 10 3 6 2 10
2 9 9 1 1 4 5 1 3 5 3 8 8 2 9 7 4 8 10 5 8 4 1 7 3 3 9 10 1 2 2 9 5 4 2 5 4 3 9 1
2 10 5 5 1 9 2 7 1 6 7 2 6 7 6 5 4 7 2 4 5 1 2 9 6 8 3 10 9 4 3 10 9 10 3 3 6 6 4
3 5 10 3 8 3 8 4 9 1 1 3 3 2 2 4 1 6 7 4 5 1 8 10 7 6 2 10 5 7 7 5 10 6 7 9 8 3 4
3 9 9 4 3 5 9 10 7 4 3 7 3 7 4 9 1 9 9 5 5 3 3 8 4 3 10 9 2 1 4 2 6 3 3 2 9 7 1 5
10 6 3 10 5 2 1 8 10 2 7 2 3 2 9 3 10 6 7
```

O/P:

```
6 5 1 9 9 2 9 10 2 2 1 2 9 1 3 1 1 10 2 1 9 3 4 2 6 4 6 9 7 9 9 6 1 1 4 5 9 7 2 5
3 2 5 7 6 5 8 10 8 3 4 4 10 6 3 4 10 9 10 9 2 8 3
```

Correct O/P:

```
6 5 1 9 9 2 9 10 2 2 1 2 9 1 3 1 1 10 2 1 9 3 4 2 6 4 6 9 7 9 9 6 1 1 4 5 9 7 2 5
3 2 5 7 6 5 8 10 8 3 4 4 10 6 3 4 10 9 10 9 2 8 3 7
```

The correct solution will be:

```
ListNode* NthNode(ListNode* head, int k)
{
    int count = 0;
    ListNode* current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (count == k)
            return current;
        ++count;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL; 
}
void deleteUnvisitedNodes(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode* current = head;
    ListNode* temp;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        int k = current->val;
        temp = NthNode(current,k);
        current->next = temp;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```